# Saving the list of events from Diagnostic Tools in VS2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, debug-diagnostic-tool

Is there a way to save the list of events shown in the Visual Studio 2015 Diagnostic Tools Events tab to a file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't seem like there is a way to do this currently, but it has been suggested as a future improvement here: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/11080035-allow-excel-export-for-diagnostic-tools-events

Answer (score 1):

You can persist a list of exceptions reported in Events tab by enabling IntelliTrace recordings in Tools > Options > IntelliTrace > Advanced. This will save IntelliTrace's *.iTrace file with a list of exceptions on disk. Later you can open this file with Visual Studio.

You can find more information regarding *.iTrace files [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264963.aspx) and [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ianhu/2009/11/16/intellitrace-itrace-files/).

Comment: That creates an iTrace file which is not readable and when opened in VS only exceptions are available and neither exception messages or Call Stack text can be copied to clipboard or otherwise saved as simple text that can be shared or emailed so you'd have to take screenshots...