# Visual Studio 2017 - Export Diagnostic Data

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

Is there a way to export data from the Diagnostic Tools in Visual Studio 2017? I'm specifically looking to export the data in the Events tab.

Comment: I don't think it's possible, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36365087/saving-the-list-of-events-from-diagnostic-tools-in-vs2015 and also https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/11080035-allow-excel-export-for-diagnostic-tools-events